# Button to add one month to current date in text field

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I currently use Access to store and easily manage gym memberships and customer information etc. I have 3 forms where employees can add a new member, view a current member, and a home page where they can run various other functions like run reports on expired memberships etc.

On the profile form which is what is opened when a member is selected there is an expiry date field which is the date the customers membership expires on. Up until now the employees of the gym have just been manually typing the date +1 month when a customer pays their membership however there have been a few mistakes.

I'm trying to create a button which will simply insert today's date +1 month into the expiry text field. To do this I have created a button and use the following VBA code, however this only adds one day, not 1 month.

```
Private Sub cmdAddDate_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorAddDate

    Me.Expiry = Date + 1

ExitAddDate:
    Exit Sub

ErrorAddDate:
    MsgBox Error.Description
    Resume ExitAddDate
End Sub
```

How can I add 1 month? I can't simply add +30, as different months have a different number of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251759.aspx) function:

```
Me.Expiry = DateAdd("m", 1, Date)
```